# angularjs date picker error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datepicker

I have a problem in my datepicker which is not working and error show

> [$compile:multidir]http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$compile/multidir?p0=datepicker&p1=&p2=da…%3D%22keydown(%24event)%22%20date-min-limit%3D%22%7B%7Bmindate%7D%7D%22%3E.

Here is my HTML where i use directive of date of datepicker and i include the bower file.

```
<!--html strat here-->
<div ng-controller="datePickerCtrl">
<datepicker date-min-limit={{mindate}}>
  <input ng-model="date" type="text"/>
</datepicker>
</div>
<!--html end here-->
```

here is my controller of date picker

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("datePickerCtrl",function($scope,$http){

       alert('hello datepicker controller');
       $scope.date = new Date();
       $scope.mindate= "date.splice(-1)";
});
```

Here is my index page code where i give code till datepicker controller file.:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>pune project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.css">
    <script src="lib/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/maincontroller.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angularjs-datepicker/src/js/angular-datepicker.js"></script> 


    <!--angular ui bootsrap @28-1-17 file cdn link here-->
     <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.13.0" data-semver="0.13.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min.js"></script>

    <!--ui grid files start here -->
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/angular-animate.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/gridController.js"></script> 
    <!--ui grid files ends here -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/kanpurcontroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/service/myFactory.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/punecontroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/delhicontroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/updateController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/demopagecontroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/modalcontroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/divgamecontroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/targetController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/target1Controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/hclcontroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/datepickercontroller.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the  module which one you are using for date picker as dependency injection on angular module in which you are using this date picker.

Comment: Which date picker your are using?

Comment: Is this the same datepicker? https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Please share the link of datepicker you are using

Comment: there is a console error. Your template file for the datepicker is itself not loading. Make sure that the template file load properly.

Comment: error has been solved i have added ui bootstrap added in app.js